# Why is $ w^{2n} + w^n + 1 = 0 $?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that $w^2 + w + 1 =0$ is true for the cube roots of unity, but why is $ w^{2n} + w^n + 1 = 0 $? I have seen this result in various websites but none of them has the derivation. The source is  askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/complex-numbers/… its there under "Now, we consider some of the key results on nth roots of unity-". How is this derived? I tried substituting (-1-w) for w^2 to get $(-1-w)^{2n} + w^n + 1 = 0$ but that just complicates things.

Comment: It is not true if $n$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: where did you even see this?

Comment: @JoBe  https://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/complex-numbers/nth-roots-of-unity.aspx its there under "Now, we consider some of the key results on nth roots of unity-"

Comment: @SaucyO'Path but why is it true?

Comment: It says "in general $1 + \omega^n + \omega^{2n} = 0$; where $n ∈ I$ but is not the multiple of $3$".

Comment: When $n$ and $3$ are coprime, $n$ can be treated as the generator of $(Z_3,+)$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it’s not even true when $n=1$, since $1$ is a cube root of unity but does not satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $w=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ and $\bar{w}=e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ (which both are solutions to $x^2+x+1=0$), then consider $w^n$.

- If $3\mid n$ then $n=3k$. Thus $w^n=e^{2\pi i k}=1$ and $w^{2n}+w^n+1=0$ is false.
- If $n=3k\pm1$ then $w^n=e^{2\pi i k\pm\frac{2\pi i}{3}}=e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$. Thus if $w^n=w$, $w^{2n}=\bar w$, and vice versa. In either case you get $w+\bar w+1=0$ or $\bar w+w+1=0$, which are both true.

---

Another, perhaps easier, way to see why $$w^{2n}+w^{n}+1=0\tag{1}$$ is true when $3\not\mid n$ is to rewrite $(1)$ as $(w^n)^2+(w^n)^1+(w^n)^0$. Then it becomes clear that this is a geometric series which equals $$\frac{(w^n)^3-1}{w^n-1}=w^{2n}+w^n+1\tag{2}$$ Now $w$ is a third root of unity, so $(w^n)^3=1$, and $w^n\neq 1\iff3\not\mid n$. From this eq. $(2)$ gives the desired result.

Notice that this last approach generalizes the result:

> Let $p$ be a prime number, and $\theta\in\mathbb{C}$ a $p$th root of unity, that is $\theta^p=1$. If $\theta\neq 1$ then $$\theta^{(p-1)n}+\ldots+\theta^2+\theta+1=0\iff p\not\mid n$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $w$ be a primitive cube root of $1$. Then $w^3=1$ and:
$$
(w^n)^3=(w^3)^n=1^n=1
$$
So, $w^n$ is also a cube root of 1. Now it remains to show that $w^n=1$ if and only if $n=3k$.